# Getting Error in quickblox connection

Tags: quickblox

I have developed login with Facebook script using the quickblox API for ios

My problem is if I enter following details, which I have got from the sample quickblox code:-

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:92];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationKey:@"wJHdOcQSxXQGWx5"];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"BTFsj7Rtt27DAmT"];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:@"7yvNe17TnjNUqDoPwfqp"];
```

Everything works perfectly fine and the user list of the application is displayed. But, if I use following details which I have created from my signup:-

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:11532];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationKey:@"dVefUXHppL86GNm"];   
[QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"MVhRuvu54Rc-9vf"];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:@"9DxpqJzCtjX9uRKkTbqN"];
```

Then I get this error:-

```
{"error":{"message":"Missing client_id parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":101}}
```